# How to update ruby version in openSuse Leap 42.1 without yast lost?

Tags: ruby, opensuse

Recently, I did such a thing: update ruby version to 2.2 through yast and change all relative executable files to new installed ones, such as cp ruby.ruby2.2 to ruby, gem.ruby2.2 to gem, and so on. However, the sad event is that **yast doesn't display its gui**. In one words, yast itself destroyed itself.

Comment: You should not use a distribution package manager to install/update Ruby or Ruby gems. It is much better to use rvm or rbenv. http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2015/10/dont-give-up-rvm.html